# Adding ligated key in an XKB Keyboard

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb

**How to add a ligated key in an XKB keyboard?**

Ligated characters are common in most languages such as Bengali or Devanagari.
I want to produce two or more characters by one keystroke.
To do this, what code should I replace in XKB symbols file?

Answer (score 1):

With XKB only, you can't, but more advanced input methods are needed.

It's worth mentioning that the `ibus-m17n` package provides quite a few input methods for e.g. Bengali and Hindi. You may want to explore those methods and see if some of them satisfy your needs.